# Join multiple entities, 2 DbSet with one List in Entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I am trying to join following query however tagNumbers is a List while other 2 are DbEntities.

```
var x = (from e in dbContext.TagCollections
            join m in dbContext.MapTagEntities on e.TagId equals m.TagId
            where m.StartDate < DateTime.UtcNow 
                  && m.EndDate > DateTime.UtcNow && e.TagNumber == tagNumber
            join t in tagNumbers on t equals e.TagNumber
            select m
        ).ToList();
```

I am getting compilation error. Is it possible to join these queries.

Comment: shouldnt second join call before where?

Comment: I tried that as well. Still getting compilation error

Comment: So tagNumbers contains a list of tags you want to retrieve?

Comment: please post what error you see here, it would be helpful for finding out what's wrong more quickly.

Comment: @KingKing: Thanks for hint, I never knew order of join conditions among equal clause matters. I will post correct answer.

Comment: ah yes, I see that error

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to King King for his hint. Position of operands matter in join here. `e.TagNumber equals t`

```
var x = (from e in dbContext.TagCollections
            join m in dbContext.MapTagEntities on e.TagId equals m.TagId
            where m.StartDate < DateTime.UtcNow 
                  && m.EndDate > DateTime.UtcNow && e.TagNumber == tagNumber
            join t in tagNumbers on e.TagNumber equals t
            select m
        ).ToList();
```